# Calling Global function defined in static library causes linker error

Tags: c++, static, global

I have created a simple static library project and a Win32 console project to call a function.

```
// static lib code
// Test.h
void abf();

// Test.cpp
void abf()
{
}

// Caller Project code
// MyTest.cpp
#include "Test.h
int main()
{
    abf();
    return 0;
}
```

Static library compiles without an error. But caller project gives following error.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl abf(void)" (?abf@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main
```

I tried a few things such as putting the function in extern "C" block, exporting using __declspec(dllexport) but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to link this library in your code?

Comment: Yes, I have added the lib in the linker. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Export your symbols using  __declspec(dllexport) in test.h

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void abf(void);
```

Comment: Also add #pragma comment(lib, "test.lib") to test.h (or make sure that test.lib is added in the project's properties)